# Oracle SQL - Column with unix timestamp, need dd-mm-yyyy timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle

is there any way in Oracle, to get only the dd-mm-yyyy part from an unix timestamp in oracle?

Like:

```
select to_char(my_timestamp, 'ddmmyyyy') as my_new_timestamp from table
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given this data ...

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss'
  2  /

Session altered.

SQL> select * from t23
  2  /

MY_TIMESTAMP
--------------------
08-mar-2010 13:06:02
08-mar-2010 13:06:08
13-mar-1985 13:06:26

SQL>
```

.. it is simply a matter of converting [the time elapsed since 01-JAN-1970](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php) into seconds:

```
SQL> select my_timestamp
  2        , (my_timestamp - date '1970-01-01') * 86400 as unix_ts
  3  from t23
  4  /

MY_TIMESTAMP            UNIX_TS
-------------------- ----------
08-mar-2010 13:06:02 1268053562
08-mar-2010 13:06:08 1268053568
13-mar-1985 13:06:26  479567186

SQL>
```

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, A Unix timestamp is defined as a number of seconds since 1970-01-01, in which case:

```
select DATE '1970-01-01' + my_timestamp/86400 from table;
```

(There are 86400 seconds in a day.)

To ignore the hours, minutes and seconds:

```
select TRUNC(DATE '1970-01-01' + my_timestamp/86400) from table;
```

However, if what you want is a "truncated" Unix timestamp then try this:

```
select floor(my_timestamp/84600)*84600 from dual;
```

Comment: my problem is : after this it want an unix timestamp not oracle date ;)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's:

```
select to_char(my_timestamp, 'dd-mm-yyyy') as my_new_timestamp from table
```

See also [this reference](http://www.oradev.com/oracle_date_format.jsp) on Oracle's date format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Unix timestamp is seconds since Jan 01 1970. (UTC).

To get Unix timestamp of now, try the follwing sql:

```
select (CAST(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(current_timestamp) AS date) - to_date('1970-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) * 86400 FROM dual;
```

You can replace `current_timestamp` with any timestamp-value.

BTW, some answers seem to return seconds since Jan 01, 1970 with local time zone. That's wrong.