# Oracle current_timestamp to seconds conversion

Tags: oracle

We are using Oracle database.

In our table timestamp is stored as seconds since 1970, how can I convert the time stamp obtained through current_timestamp() function to  seconds

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle SQL - Column with unix timestamp, need dd-mm-yyyy timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401396/oracle-sql-column-with-unix-timestamp-need-dd-mm-yyyy-timestamp)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This would do it:

```
select round((cast(current_timestamp as date) - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60) from dual
```

Though I wouldn't use current_timestamp if I was only interested in seconds, I would use SYSDATE:

```
select round((SYSDATE - date '1970-01-01')*24*60*60) from dual
```

Comment: I would add `ROUND()` around that - otherwise you can get a result like `1425030807.000000000000000000000000000004`. Also, doesn't everyone know that there are 86,400 seconds in a day? ;)

Comment: Warning: Unix time is GMT/UTC and Oracle sysdate is the local time. So not sure if this solution will be exact

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not completely relevant. I had to resolve other way around problem (e.g. Oracle stores timestamp in V$RMAN_STATUS and V$RMAN_OUTPUT) and I had to convert that to date/timestamp. I was surprised, but the magic date is not 1970-01-01 there, but 1987-07-07. I looked at Oracle's history and the closest date I can think of is when they ported Oracle products to UNIX. Is this right?

Here's my SQL

```
SELECT /*+ rule */
         to_char(min(stamp)/(24*60*60) + date '1987-07-07', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') start_tm
       , to_char(to_char(max(stamp)/(24*60*60) + date '1987-07-07', 'DD-MON HH24:MI:SS')) end_tm
FROM V$RMAN_STATUS 
START WITH (RECID, STAMP) =
     (SELECT MAX(session_recid),MAX(session_stamp) FROM V$RMAN_OUTPUT) 
CONNECT BY PRIOR RECID = parent_recid ;
```

Comment: Been in the exact same situation. I calculated the initial date of Oracle as "1987-05-26 00:00:00".

Answer (score 0):

I needed to send timestamp to GrayLog via GELF from Oracle DB. I tried different versions and solutions but only one worked correctly.

SQL:

```
SELECT REPLACE((CAST(dat AS DATE) - TO_DATE('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD')) * 86400 + MOD(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM dat), 1), ',', '.') AS millis
FROM (SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT' AS dat FROM dual)
```

The result for Systmiestamp

> 2018/12/18 19:47:29,080988 +02:00

will be

```
1545155249.080988
```