# Oracle Number data type to datetime format

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Oracle current_timestamp to seconds conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881235/oracle-current-timestamp-to-seconds-conversion)
>   [Convert Unixtime to Datetime SQL (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554405/convert-unixtime-to-datetime-sql-oracle)

I have been given a database wherein the datetime/timestamp column has been defined in NUMBER data type. What oracle function should i use to get the date time out of it?

Ex. In my table : Sample_Table, column time_touched is defined with oracle data type NUMBER. This column is supposed to be date time/timestamp. When I query the DB, I get numbers like 1355218434,1355218851 etc. These are representation of date time. But in query, what function should i use to get it display date time?

Comment: Whats the number?  There isn't any way to answer this if you don't give information about the format of the current data.

Comment: Brett, see if its any better now?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a UNIX timestamp (seconds since epoch 1970-01-01) where for example 1355218434 represents Tue, 11 Dec 2012 09:33:54 GMT ([see converter here](http://www.epochconverter.com/))

**EDIT**: Apparently the example below only works for MySQL, I thought that it also worked on Oracle because of the domain it is on but I was wrong. The solution is in the answer in this StackOverflow question: [Convert Unixtime to Datetime SQL (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554405/convert-unixtime-to-datetime-sql-oracle)

---

You could use the `FROM_UNIXTIME` function to get what you want, see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.0-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime for reference.

Try something like this (untested):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(time_touched) FROM Sample_Table
```

---

Your question is somewhat related to:

https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2473501&tstart=75

[Convert Unixtime to Datetime SQL (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554405/convert-unixtime-to-datetime-sql-oracle)

Comment: `FROM_UNIXTIME` is MySQL, not Oracle. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554405/convert-unixtime-to-datetime-sql-oracle has a solution...

Comment: My bad, thought it was for Oracle since it was on that page. The good thing is that the answer was in the related links i posted. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: We should ask Oracle Inc to stop buying tech companies as googling for documentation becomes increasingly harder :-)

Comment: @WolfgangFleischmann No kidding.. :)